# cannot import name 'empty_generator' from 'networkx.utils'

Tags: python, networkx

I am getting this error:

```
cannot import name 'empty_generator' from 'networkx.utils'
```

When trying to import networkx:

```
import networkx as nx
```

I have already tried to uninstall it, and install it back. It did not work.

Comment: What network version are you using?

Comment: network version 2.5

Comment: See:  https://github.com/conda-forge/osmnx-feedstock/issues/78 - upgrade to a newer network version is probably the easiest